# Install 20.04 on external SSD without disabling Intel RST

Tags: system-installation

I tried a daily build of 20.04 in March and was able to install it to an external SSD no problem.

I tried to install a daily build today and the installer is telling me to disable Intel RST before installing.

I don’t want to touch the internal disk, I just want to install to the external SSD but I can’t see any way to achieve that now. Am I missing something?

Comment: A workaround would be to unplug the internal drive, or disconnect it or disable it in BIOS. Then your external drive sill be accepted as a target. Afterwards it is possible to connect the internal drive again and select booting via a temporary menu at boot. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) may help.

Comment: We don't support 20.04 yet. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See [post on discourse about RST](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347?u=norbert).

Comment: It's a shame that the installer no longer provides the option to select the target disk.

Comment: Which flavour of Ubuntu are you using? There is a difference between Lubuntu, which uses the installer Calamares, and the other Ubuntu desktop flavours, which use the installer Ubiquity. An alternative for you could be to install Ubuntu Server, which uses the old text mode Debian installer or Ubuntu Live Server, which uses the installer Curtin and install only the basic system (without specific server packages) and then reboot and install the Ubuntu desktop package, that you want, for example `sudo apt ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt lubuntu-desktop` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus, I disabled the internal drive that uses RST in the bios and was then able to install to my external SSD. I'm using vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 and will remember your suggestion to use the Ubuntu server installer in future.